# UTImportedTypeDeclarations are not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add OPML import/export option to my app. Experiencing the following problems:

1) Importing OPML is working correctly until I install any other app that uses OPML. Files become "greyed out" and unavailable

2) icons for OMPL files are not showing despite assets are set up (both 22x29 and 44x58 pixels)

Using the code below added in Info.plist:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>icon_44x58</string>
            <string>icon_22x29</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.tuneVu.opml</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>opml</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>text/x-opml</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>icon_44x58</string>
            <string>icon_22x29</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.tuneVu.opml</string>
        <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>opml</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>text/x-opml</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```